# WCF consolidate RESTful and SOAP listener

Tags: wcf, rest, soap, solid-principles

I'm trying to make a single WCF application that will allow me to receive either SOAP or RESTful messages and essentially process them the same way.  I do have code that "works" but I'm not sure it's implemented in the most efficient manner, so I'm wondering how this can be accomplished more elegantly.

I have the following code:

```
class Interfaces
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "myNameSpace")]
    public interface IMessageBrokers_SOAP
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke]
        bool Broker_SOAP_Messages(string source, string destination,Dictionary<string, string> Incoming_Message);
    }

    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "myNameSpace")]
    public interface ImessageBrokers_REST
    {
        [OperationContract, WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        bool Broker_REST_Messages();
    }
}

class MessageBrokers : Interfaces.IMessageBrokers_SOAP, Interfaces.ImessageBrokers_REST
{
    public bool Broker_SOAP_Messages(string source, string destination,Dictionary<string, string> Incoming_Values)
    {
        //take the object passed in and pass it along to wholesale to Broker_Message
        return Broker_Message(source, destination, Incoming_Values);
    }

    public bool Broker_REST_Messages()
    {
        //take the query params and put them into dictionary for Broker_Message to use
        var queryParameters = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters;
        Dictionary<string, string> Incoming_Values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (string key in queryParameters.AllKeys)
        {
            string value = queryParameters[key];
            Incoming_Values.Add(key, value);
        }

        return Broker_Message(queryParameters["source"], queryParameters["destination"], Incoming_Values);

    }

    bool Broker_Message(string source, string destination, Dictionary<string, string> Incoming_Values)
    {
            //do work
    }
}
```

But I feel like I'm going about this the wrong way.  I'd like to use inheritance for this, but I can't seem to get it to work without having two separate code sets.

Comment: Why do you have two separate definitions for `Broker_*_Message`?  Why not just one implementation?  The attributes you place on the method definitions in the interface along with the endpoints exposed should take care of your needs, unless there's a design reason/limitation forcing different implementations of the method(s).

Comment: If I understand your question correctly.. I implemented it this way because I could think of no other way to handle a SOAP message that contains a dicitonary vs. a REST message that contains KVP's passed as query parameters.. I guess that's what I'm asking.. is there a better way to accomplish that?

Comment: You could put them all in the same interface, just decorate the methods with the proper attributes (depending on whether you want SOAP or REST), if the method implementations need to be different between the two.  If the SOAP and REST methods are truly different, then you will need separate method definitions in the interface, but you don't need one interface per method.  Then you simply have your service implement the interface.

Comment: Any chance you can give me an example of that.. I'm pretty sure that's what I've been trying to do.. but I can only get the interface to handle one or the other so far.